# SQL query tune up

Tags: sql

How can I optimize the below query?

```
DELETE FROM #Data 
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID)
                 FROM #Data 
                 GROUP BY SerialNumber, VendorName)
```

It takes like up to 2 minutes to execute.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    ID                 INT IDENTITY (1, 1),
    ItemSupplierKey    INT          NOT NULL,   
    SerialNumber       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    VendorName         VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);
```

It contains 257316 records.

Here are indexes on this temp table:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX PX_Data ON #Data (SerialNumber, VendorName);
CREATE INDEX IX_Data ON #Data (ID);
```

Comment: FYI, this is probably a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your second index is on `#AliasData`, not `#Data` - an index on `ID` in `#Data` should speed things up significantly (although there may be other factors as well).

Comment: Sorry it's actually #Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see a performance increase by using a `common table expression` with `row_number()`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber, VendorName ORDER BY ID) RN
    FROM Data
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN != 1
```

Comment: Awesome! It reduced the execution time from 90 to 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to rewrite the delete to use a `left join` to join the same `#Data` table and delete where the joined records are `null`:

```
delete d
from #Data d
    left join (
         SELECT MIN(ID) as ID FROM #Data GROUP BY SerialNumber, VendorName
    ) t1 on d.ID = t1.ID
where t1.ID is null
```